# IntentService starting new service - on which thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

I have a maintenance IntentService that uses an AlarmManager to start my main service every 30 seconds.
The reason I use an IntentService is because I want my MainService to run on a background thread.

My question is- if an IntentService starts a new service using startService(new Intent(this, MainService.class));, which thread is the MainService starting on? the IntentService's thread or the UI thread?

Here's my code: Thanks in advance!

```
/**
* A service that maintains all the required parts of Smoove alive. In case of a
* system startup or a crash of the main service, WatchDogService restarts the
* required service
*/
public class WatchDogService extends IntentService {

// Holds the alarm manager instance.
AlarmManager alarmMgr = null;


public WatchDogService() {
    super("WatchDogService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    log.info("WatchDogService onHandleIntent");
    Intent intentMainService = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
    intentMainService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startService(intentMainService);

    }

    if(!isRegisteredToAlarmManager){
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        registerToAlarmManager();
    }
}

// Registers the service to the alarm manager. to start in every INTERVAK
// seconds.
private void registerToAlarmManager() {
    // Build the intent.
    log.info("entered registerToAlarmManager");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),WatchDogService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Pull the alarm manager service to register the service.
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
            INTERVAL * 1000, pendingIntent);

    isRegisteredToAlarmManager = true;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Services always run the **main** thread of their process. The thread from which you run `startService()` should be immaterial at best (at worst, it could create problems, but not make the called service run in that thread).

(Just to clarify: so does `IntentService` -- it only calls [`onHandleIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) on a background thread).

Comment: probably it would be a bit more clear if you say *run in the main thread*

Comment: Check in your new service if that is main thread: Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread(); OR print id: Thread.currentThread().getId()